# Slim Framework 4 getParsedBody Always returns null

Tags: php, slim, slim-4

I'm testing Slim Framework 4 and I can't seem to be able to retrieve any data when I'm submiting a JSON via POST, using the getParsedBody method, it always results in NULL. Here is my endpoint:

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app->post('/prueba', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $data = $request->getParsedBody();
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($data));
    return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        ->withStatus(200);
});
```

Following some docs I've added the BodyParsing Middleware:

```
<?php

use Dotenv\Dotenv;
use Slim\Views\Twig;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use Slim\Views\TwigExtension;
use Slim\Psr7\Factory\UriFactory;
use Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    (new Dotenv(__DIR__ . '/../'))->load();
} catch (InvalidPathException $e) {
    //
}

$container = new DI\Container();

AppFactory::setContainer($container);

$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->addBodyParsingMiddleware();

$app->addRoutingMiddleware();

$app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);

$container->set('settings', function () {
    return [
        'app' => [
            'name' => getenv('APP_NAME')
        ],
        'db' => [
            'driver' => getenv('DB_DRIVER'),
            'host' => getenv('DB_HOST'),
            'database' => getenv('DB_NAME'),
            'username' => getenv('DB_USER'),
            'password' => getenv('DB_PASS'),
            'charset' => getenv('DB_CHARSET'),
            'collation' => getenv('DB_COLLATION'),
            'prefix' => ''
        ]
    ];
});

$capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager();
$capsule->addConnection($container->get('settings')['db']);
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();

$container->set('view', function ($container) use ($app) {
    $twig = new Twig(__DIR__ . '/../resources/views', [
        'cache' => false
    ]);

    $twig->addExtension(
        new TwigExtension(
            $app->getRouteCollector()->getRouteParser(),
            (new UriFactory)->createFromGlobals($_SERVER),
            '/'
        )
    );

    return $twig;
});

require_once __DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php';
```

This is the request I'm sending:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:80/prueba' \
--header 'Content-type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"name": "Rob", "country": "UK"}'
```

I've debuged a little and verified that the middleware is processing the request but up until now I can't get it to return anything else than null. Also looked over and there doesn't seem to be any reported issue with a definitive solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, It was a problem caused by a deficient skeleton, using the oficial skeleton from slim everything was solved

Comment: This answer should not be downvoted (although it does not seem to be too helpful at the first glance).  
I had a similar problem. Usually you get the advice to add '$app->addBodyParsingMiddleware();' for this, but it did not work in my case. I deleted the vendor folder, reinstalled everything by "composer install", and after this it worked fine.